# array index out of range tableview has a load more button

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview which gets its data from a NSDate array. I'm returning the array count + 1 as the number of rows in my tableview because I want a button at the bottom of tableview to allow user to load more cells. Here is part of my codes:

```
var dates = [NSDate]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == dates.count + 1 {

        let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("loadMoreCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LoadMoreTableViewCell

        cell.loadmoreButton.targetForAction("loadmore", withSender: self)
        cell.loadmoreButton.addTarget(self, action: "loadmore:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        return cell

    } else {

        let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TestingViewCell


        //cell.date.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dates[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an array index out of range error for the line commented out, what should I do? thanks in advance!

Comment: `if indexPath.row == dates.count` instead? Imagine that dates contains 2 elements. You want to show 2 elements + More Cell. So that makes 3, but your indexPath will be (for row), 0 (dates1), 1(dates2) and 2(morecell), where dates.count will be 2.

Comment: @larme thanks! solved my problem